# Loop through YAML Entitys does not return the content

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, go, yaml

I'm trying to work a little bit with Go and YAML and I'm new in this field. 
In my YAML file named users.yaml you can find the following content:

```yaml
    - fullName: Mx Mustermann
      givenName: Max
      familyName: Mustermann
      primaryEmail: max.mustermann@test.de
      validUntil: 20 Apr 20 10:00 UTC
    - fullName: Berta Beispiel
      givenName: Berta
      familyName: Beispiel
      primaryEmail: berta.beispiel@test.de
      validUntil: 20 Apr 20 10:00 UTC
```

I want to process the content of this YAML file now. The goal is that I can output an attribute for each defined user in yaml in a loop.
I have programmed the following so far:

```golang
    package main

    import (
        "errors"
        "fmt"
        "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
        "io/ioutil"
    )

    type users struct{
        fullName string
        givenName string
        familyName string
        primaryEmail string
        validUntil string
    }

    func readUsersFile(filePath string)([]*users,error){
        var us []*users
        yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)

        if err != nil{
            return us,errors.New("Unable to read yaml file ")
        }
        if err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &us); err !=nil{
            return us, fmt.Errorf("can not parse your yaml file %s", err)
        }
        return us, nil
    }


    func main(){
        entities, err := readUsersFile("users/users.yaml")
        if err != nil{
            fmt.Errorf("Error return value readUsersFile ")
        }

            for _, entity := range entities {
                fmt.Println("PrimaryEmail:", entity.primaryEmail)
            }
    }
```

The loop also works logically. For example, if I remove a user from users.yaml, it will only return the string "PrimaryEmail" again. But the content is missing. So entity.primaryEmail.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your fields are unexported. You can't unmarshal into unexported fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
Like I said. I am completely new to the world of Go. Do you have any tips on how I can fix this?

Comment: Make the fields exported. https://tour.golang.org/basics/3

Comment: It's also explained in detail in the docs for the YAML package you're using https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshal

Comment: Thank you very much